# Google Keyboard crashes during a drag operation

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, crash, android-softkeyboard

So, this is an odd one.

I have implemented a custom ScrollView that allows drag and sort operation on a list of items by intercepting touch events. This works well enough on three out of four devices that I have tested on.

On Dell 7 tablet running 4.4.2, the behavior is really strange. The movement while dragging is rough. And in the middle of a drag, the Google Keyboard crashes. This happens irrespective of whether the keyboard is currently open or not. And no exceptions are present in my logs. The app continues to function as before - perhaps a bit more smoother - this happens once after the activity starts - on the first drag operation. After this, the keyboard and the drag-sort work as expected.

There were a few mentions of spell-checker events (not sure if they were indicative of an exception) in the System and event log included in the crash report. These spell-checker log statements were output right before the keyboard crash. So, I checked whether the spell check was turned on. The three devices on which the app functioned fine had the spell-check off. Only the Dell tablet had the spell-check on.

Next, I turned off the spell-check on Dell tab and the keyboard crashes stopped. This is very unusual, and I can't wrap my head around it.

Has someone experienced this behavior? If there exists a bug report detailing the issue, it'll be great if someone could point to it.

Thank you for reading. I did not include any code because I don't know what the relevant part(s) would be.

Comment: I haven't done much with the Google keyboard recently, but it sounds like it was assuming that the spellchecker service was non-null.  I know no other keyboard requires this, its a google specific thing (or possibly even Dell specific) because all Samsung devices ship with that off and no way to turn it on in settings.  If you're really interested, check the latinIME and make sure it null checks any calls to newSpellCheckedSession and getSystemService(Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE)

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan I looked at `com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME.java` but could not locate those calls. I''ll browse through package `com.android.inputmethod.latin` some more. Why is it that a drag operation (indirectly?) initiates a call to the spell-checker service - even when the keyboard is not in use?

Comment: I have no idea.  I'm basing it off your report of what fixed it.  My only guess is that it tried to launch the keyboard and it was in some initialization code (possibly indirectly).